# Bind keyboard shortcut to one key in AutoHotkey with delay

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

I am using the Japanese IME on Windows 10. TL;DR there is a shortcut to switch from alphanumeric (latin alphabet) to Japanese input. The combination is ALT+` [l or r alt + tilde key]. For it to work, both keys must be held down but the alt key must be pressed first. I am trying to bind this combination to one key.

I have been able to bind normal letter keys to a combination of other letters (e.g. a -> b + c) but I cannot get it to work with the keys I need, and especially not because there needs to be a delay between them. The code confuses me.

Comment: ```ScrollLock::!` ```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: The [basic binding stuff](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm): when you press ScrollLock it sends Alt `

Comment: Brilliant that worked, I don't know why I didn't try that, thanks!